# Use javascript to reload json properties without hard resetting webpage

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

JSON example:

```
[{
    "client": "client1",
    "ip": "127.0.0.1",
    "status": "up"
}, {
    "client": "client2",
    "ip": "127.0.0.2",
    "status": "up"
}]
```

I have this script to read the JSON file and create tables and apply color to tables according to JSON information:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $.getJSON("<urltojson>/clients.json",
    function (data) {

        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);

           if(data[i].status == "up")
            {
              $('td',tr).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
             } else {
              $('td',tr).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
            };
        }
    });

    </script>
```

The JSON file itself gets updated through a backend python script. Everything works as intended. However, if I want to see update information from JSON file I need to hard-reload the webpage, which is pretty easy to do. But I want javascript to auto reload JSON in the background and apply conditions gracefully without a hard reload of the webpage.

It's probably something trivial to do , but my lack of js knowledge is not helping me. I did a couple of hours worth research without any luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: who is triggering $.getJSON?

Comment: If you want the data to change on the client when it changes on the server, you'll need either ... polling, server sent events, or websockets.

Comment: You need to put your code in a function, figure out what you want to use as a trigger (button click, timer, etc), and call the function when that event occurs.

Comment: no one is. the script is in the header, loading the site gets triggered.

Comment: Can't you just wrap your code in a Timeout / Interval? See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: Search for "long polling": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077857/what-are-long-polling-websockets-server-sent-events-sse-and-comet

Comment: Well, you already have a $.getJSON() function which uses AJAX, now you need something to call that function within an interval: `setInterval()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval

Comment: The code examples I got so far didn't work at all (I have come to similar results in my research). I am looking into long polling now. I think there might be another issue of new result not replacing the previous result inthe table just amending at the bottom of the table.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply call your function, and related getJSON jQuery method every 3 seconds with an interval as such;

```
window.setInterval(function(){ getJson(); myFunc(); }, 3000);
```

Comment: I am getting this error on browser inspect console: `7
Uncaught TypeError: getJson is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval or setTimeout to fetch JSON every few seconds.

```
var timeToRefresh = 5 * 1000; // 5 seconds
setTimeout(function fetchData() {
  $.getJSON("<urltojson>/clients.json",
    function (data) {

        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
            $('table').append(tr);

           if(data[i].status == "up")
            {
              $('td',tr).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
             } else {
              $('td',tr).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
            };
        }
    });
  setTimeout(fetchData, timeToRefresh);
}, timeToRefresh);
```

I know that isn't a perfect solution but i hope it will works.

Comment: Hello I have tried this before. Instead of updating the existing table, it just appends more table at the bottom of the previous and goes on and on. Not ideal of course.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating table in your code, but this object is not displayed on your page.
Try like this:

```
var timeToRefresh = 5 * 1000; // 5 seconds
setTimeout(function fetchData() {
  $.getJSON("<urltojson>/clients.json",
    function (data) {

        var tr;
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<td>" + data[i].client +  "</td>");
            $('#myTable').append(tr);

           if(data[i].status == "up")
            {
              $('td',tr).css ('background-color', '#88d066');
             } else {
              $('td',tr).addClass("statusHOSTDOWN");
            };
        }
    });
  setTimeout(fetchData, timeToRefresh);
}, timeToRefresh);
```

**html**

```
 <table id="myTable"></table>
```

Comment: Same issue as @emil Pausz code. and yes I forgot to add table on my example but it was properly used on my working code.